# Dropping the '.00' when printing floats that hold whole numbers

Tags: javascript, decimal, point

I'm currently displaying a quantity in Javascript. I want it to display (for example) the whole number as `89` instead of `89.00`; however, if the number is fractional like `89.50` then it should display `89.50`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript printf/string.format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear if your question is about parsing floats or about checking integers. Here is a function that accepts numbers or strings and returns the float formatted as a string:

```
function displayQuantity(n) {
  return parseFloat(n).toFixed(n%1 ? 2 : 0);
}
```

In case you have to support (very) old browsers, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337112/how-to-write-a-prototype-for-number-tofixed-in-javascript) for an implementation of `Number#toFixed`.