# Trying to round an object value in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, rounding

I have seemingly a very simple little script...

```
function speedcomp(obj) {
    obj.speedmile.value = 3600 / obj.timesec.value
}

function distcomp(obj) {
    if (obj.speed.value == "")
        obj.speed.value = ((1 * obj.distance.value) / obj.day.value) / 24;
    else if (obj.distance.value == "")
        obj.distance.value = distance.value;
    else if (obj.day.value == "")
        obj.day.value = ((1 * obj.distance.value) / obj.speed.value) / 24;
    obj.hour.value = ((1 * obj.distance.value) / obj.speed.value);
}​
```

I have 4 input type text's with id's of distance, speed, day, and hour.  When I put in a speed and distance and click a button who's onclick="distcomp(this.form)"  it does the math for me nicely.

The issue I am having is trying to round the values for day and hour to the nearest 100th.  Since I am not presetting the values I am finding my self struggling with Math.round and Math.floor.  I believe the answer will be using Math.round but I could use some.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [`toFixed`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.5):

```
var num = Math.random();
alert(num.toFixed(2));
```

There are some buggy implementations around IE 6, and javascript decimals aren't precise for some values so you might get unexpected results:

```
(0.595).toFixed(2) // 0.59 in Firefox, 0.60 in IE
```

If you use:

```
Math.round(num*100)/100
```

then you will not get the right padding (0.59 => 0.6 not 0.60). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) has some other interesting snippets.

There seems to be a reasonable replacement for `toFixed` in answer to [How to write a prototype for Number.toFixed in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337112/how-to-write-a-prototype-for-number-tofixed-in-javascript).

#### Edit

Here is a reasonable toFixed function, I'll keep testing to make sure it's reasonably ES5 compliant. For `toFixed(0,2)` it returns `0.00` whereas the spec says `0` but I think the former is more useful.

```
function toFixed(num, places) {

    var m, s = '', t;
    num = Number(num);

    if (isNaN(num)) return 'NaN';

    if (num < 0) {
      s = '-';
      num = num * -1;
    }

    m = Math.pow(10, places || 0);
    num = String(Math.round(num * m) / m).split('.');
    t = num[1] || '';
    num[1] = t + (new Array(places - t.length + 1)).join('0');

    return s + num.join('.');
};
```

Jasper's comment seems like a good solution:

```
(Math.round(.595*100)/100).toFixed(2);
```

though `(0).toFixed(2)` gives `0` (per EMCA-262) rather than the more useful `0.00`, which is why the above avoids `toFixed`.

Comment: You could fix the rounding first and then use `toFixed`: `(Math.round(.595*100)/100).toFixed(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

To round to the nearest 100th, multiply the number by 100, call `Math.round()` and then divide by 100 again.

```
num=210.653434343
Math.round(num*100)/100
210.65
```

To round to the 100s place, divide first, round, then multiply. You can also change 100 to any other place and it will work for that. (change 100 to 10 for 10s and 10ths place)

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what the number is until it has been calculated. Also it is going to the nearest hundredth(ie. 210.653434343 would go to 210.65).

Comment: so? it's a variable. Just put in whatever variable holds the value instead of "num". And I misread, hundredTH is similar, just swap the / and *

Comment: I never set a var, what I originally posted is all the code I have.

Comment: How do you work with the number in your code? What number do you want to round? Is it `obj.day.value`? If so, replace `num` with `obj.day.value`. I can't help if you don't know what variable has the value you want to work with.

Comment: I am still at a loss.  I do not have a variable other than obj.day.value and obj.hour.value.  I call on it simply with an <input type="text" id="day"or"hour"/>

Comment: Thank you!

so I did this....
    
    obj.hour.value = Math.round(((1 * obj.distance.value) / obj.speed.value)*100)/100 ;